# htaccess rewrite not working beyond first directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have had to change the name of a page on my wordpress site. In the url structure the page has many sub pages which are illustrated as follows:

```
www.mysite.com/folder1/plus whatever else may come here
```

Basically I want to do a wildcard redirect where any URL matching the folder1 part of the URL gets caught and redirected to the following:

```
www.mysite.com/newfolder1/folder2/
```

The following redirect works for the above situation

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/?(.*) http://www.mysite.com/newfolder1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But fails and give a 404 for the following

```
www.mysite.com/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

It will not redirect beyond the folder2 depth. Why is this?

Comment: In which folder is your htaccess file that has this rule?

Comment: Hi Jon, its in the root. It is being picked up alright and I can see wordpress's stuff in there too. It just does not seem to work for directories of a lower depth.

Comment: Can you paste your full htaccess here? Just wondering if another rule is preventing that one from working...

Comment: Jon my apologies to you, this was a silly mistake on my part but a good lesson. You were indeed correct. The htaccess I was editing was on the wordpress install root, but when I checked ahain there is another on the server root which funnily also has references to the wordpress install. I copied in the redirect here and it works at all levels. I wonder why the initial one only worked for the second level? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jon If you add a quick answer Jon about what I was doing wrong on this I will accept it for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the comments:

The problem sounds like the `.htaccess` file (or the rules you're talking about) is in the wrong location.

[As far as my understanding goes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html), Apache reads all the `.htaccess` files (and other server configs that do redirects) from the "top" down - i.e., `.htaccess` files in subfolders are processed **after** `.htaccess` files in the root folder.

Comment: Cheers for the help Jon, you got me on the right track. Much appreciated.